# Blank fields in fillable PDF using iTextSharp stamper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

While I was waiting for someone to create a fillable PDF for me to use in my project, I substituted with a fillable tax form while writing my code. The code below filled in the tax PDF form, but when I substitute the tax form with our fillable PDF form, it no longer works. I have verified that the field names are correct (by inspecting the Fields in acroFields). Why won't my form fill? (template is the fillable form)

```
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(template))
            {
                pdfMemoryReader = new PdfReader(template);
                pdfMemoryReader.RemoveUsageRights();  // prevents the "This document enabled extended features in Adobe Reader...." message
                PdfStamper pdfMemoryStamper = null;
                try
                {
                    pdfMemoryStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfMemoryReader, memoryStream);

                    AcroFields acroMemoryFields = pdfMemoryStamper.AcroFields;

                    acroMemoryFields = PopulatePDF(studentId, termId, acroMemoryFields, PDFFields);

                    pdfMemoryStamper.FormFlattening = true;
                    pdfMemoryStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
                    if (pdfMemoryStamper != null)
                    {
                        pdfMemoryStamper.Close();
                    }
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                }
                finally
                {
                    pdfMemoryReader.Close();  //this supposedly closes the underlying stream
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        { }
        return memoryStream;
```

and PopulatePDF (I have also verified PDFFields.StudentLName has a value):

```
        public AcroFields PopulatePDF(Guid studentId, Guid termId, AcroFields acroFields, PDFViewModel PDFFields)
    {            
        SharedInfo(studentId, termId, PDFFields);
        acroFields.SetField("[StudentLName]", PDFFields.StudentLName);
        acroFields.SetField("[StudentFName]", PDFFields.StudentFName);
        acroFields.SetField("[Grade]", PDFFields.StudentFName);
     }
```

Any idea on why this new form will not fill? Is there some attribute the form needs in order to work with iTextSharp? iTextSharp is version 4.1.2.0

Comment: Are you certain that your field names contain brackets in them?  This seems both unnecessary and quite a bit odd.  In addition, why are you wrapping your entire block in a try catch if you aren't actually catching anything?

Comment: Ah, the brackets were it! When you inspect 'Fields' in the watch window they show with brackets, so I assumed... bad thing to do. I haven't completed logging yet, hence the empty catch.

Comment: Well, in that case, I'll add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to remove the brackets.  That is being "added" by the watch window.